# Using InterleavedBufferAttribute inside a InstancedBufferGeometry for instances

Tags: three.js

I have a working example of `InstancedBufferGeometry` and one using `InstancedBufferAttribute`; however I want to combine them.  [I've seen examples using interleaved on the base geometry](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_interleaved) but not on the per instance buffers.  Basically would like to gen a single arrayBuffer for all instance attributes. I'm hoping there is a stride or something I'm missing to make this happen.

Comment: Isn't the following example the one you are looking for? https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_interleaved

Comment: @Mugen87 no, that's using interleaves on the base geometry, not the per instance buffers.  That was one of the examples I saw, sorry should have included the link.